# Powershell: function parameters

Tags: events, powershell, event-viewer

I'm building a powershell function so i can query multiple computers event logs.  Ive copied the code below that i need help with.  If I don't send an eventID, I want the script to find all event ID's, how can i achieve this?

```
#this would be the parameter part of the script
[String]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME#Current computer 
[String[]]$EventLogNames=@("Application","System")#Main eventlogs 
[int[]]$EventIds = 1 #Event Ids 
[System.DateTime[]]$EventStartDate = (((Get-Date).addDays(-2)).date)#date 10 days ago 
[System.DateTime[]]$EventEndTime = (Get-Date)#date 10 days ago 

#This fits in the process section
$EventCritea = @{logname = $EventLogNames; StartTime=$EventStartDate; EndTime=$EventEndTime; ID=$EventIds}
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilterHashTable $EventCritea  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674581/get-winevent-start-and-end-dates-not-filtering-records) fixes the types of `$EventStartDate` and `$EventEndTime`.

For this question: build the hashtable incrementally:

```
$filter = @{logname = $EventLogNames; StartTime=$EventStartDate; EndTime=$EventEndTime}

if ($EventIds -ne $null -and $EventIds.Length -gt 0) {
  $filter.ID=$EventIds
}

Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilterHashTable $filter #...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. works a treat, i didnt know you could add to hashtables like that :-)