# Get-WinEvent start and end dates not filtering records

Tags: events, date, powershell

The get-winevent start and end dates are not filtering records.  Can anyone tell me why? I expect from the code below the last 2 days events but i gets dates going back to 2010 (my Windows clock date is correct)

```
[String]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME#Current computer 
[String[]]$EventLogNames=@("Application","System")#Main eventlogs 
[System.DateTime[]]$EventStartDate = (((Get-Date).addDays(-2)).date)#date 10 days ago 
[System.DateTime[]]$EventEndTime = (Get-Date)

$EventCritea = @{logname = $EventLogNames; StartTime=$EventStartDate; EndTime=$EventEndTime}
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilterHashTable $EventCritea  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error in your script is the type of your start and end date/time - they are declared as arrays.

Change

```
[System.DateTime[]]$EventStartDate = (((Get-Date).addDays(-2)).date)
[System.DateTime[]]$EventEndTime = (Get-Date)
```

to

```
[System.DateTime]$EventStartDate = (((Get-Date).addDays(-2)).date)
[System.DateTime]$EventEndTime = (Get-Date)
```

or omit them altogether

```
$EventStartDate = (((Get-Date).addDays(-2)).date)
$EventEndTime = (Get-Date)
```

Comment: Thanks, its because i copied/modified the line from above. I couldn't figure this one out.  Thanks alot for taking your time and answering :-)